# Login com angular 4

Tags: session, angular, login, localstorage

Estou aprendendo angular4, e gostaria de saber uma maneira de fazer login com o mesmo. Já consigo pegar os dados do backend, mas como configuro a sessao?(vim do php, la era so usar session).

Vi algo sobre armazenar um token no localstorage, mas isso ficaria la para sempre, nao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar como base este tutorial para criar o login com Angular

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Sobre o localStorage armazena os dados sem data de validade. Os dados não serão excluídos quando o navegador estiver fechado e estarão disponíveis no próximo dia, semana ou ano.

Você pode ver mais aqui
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp